# Run a Python script in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I am working on a python script to test the HTTP status of a group of websites and if  any website is down , an email would be triggered.

Python script : C:\Users\p\PycharmProjects\test\test.py

Now i want to schedule this script to run in a timely fashion and wanted to use jenkins for the same.

Could you please help me with basic steps or syntax needed for creating a jenkins job for the same.

Below is the jenkins job:

[image: jenkins pipeline]

output:

line 1: C:/Users/p/PycharmProjects/test/test.py: No such file or directory

Thanks

Comment: Path in your question differs from path in the job.

Comment: i tried  sh 'C:\Users\p\PycharmProjects\test\test.py' as well , but the pipeline throws syntax error saying "unexpected character : '\' "

Comment: For executing python scripts, you should invoke the python executable.

sh 'python C:\path\to\file.py' <-- windows paths uses backslashes

Comment: Use double backslash

Comment: Please check the Jenkins Slave machine where your job run has this file: `C:/Users/p/PycharmProjects/test/test.py`

Comment: 1.I tried Double backslash - still same issue

Comment: 2.I tired sh 'python C:/Users/pl57724/PycharmProjects/test/test.py' ,still same issue

Comment: I dont have access to the jenkins slave machine unix box :(